# How do I change the output power on the OS X internet sharing wifi network?

Tags: wifi, security, internet-sharing

I'm on 10.7, and I want to alter the broadcast power (so my wifi network doesn't extend beyond 10 ft radius or so). Also, if there's a way to change the security to WPA, which windows 7 can do, I'd like to know.

Comment: Your 2 questions are typical security improvment questions. I added the tag security to your original question. Note: the second part of your question has a reply, the first one not yet. Perhaps you should separate the 2 ones to improve efficiency.

Comment: 10.8 adds WPA to the wifi so that's fixed at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a good way to modify the radio broadcast power level on the built-in card on a Mac.  However, you may find that setting up a [shared internet connection using bluetooth](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110612232450787) achieves your goal of limiting the range.

Regarding your second question, there have been previous inquiries about changing the WiFi encryption protocol on Mac Ad-Hoc networks from WEP with no results.